# Keyword functions for Python min/max

Tags: python, key, min

I am trying to understand how this works:

```
my_dict = {'a':2,'b':1}
min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```

produces

```
b
```

Which is a really cool feature and one I want to understand better.
Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

> min(iterable[, key])
>   Return the smallest item in an iterable or the smallest of two or more arguments...
>   The optional key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort(). The key argument, if supplied, must be in keyword form (for example, min(a,b,c,key=func)).

Where can I find out more about available functions?  In the case of a dictionary, is it all the dictionary methods?

Edit: I came across this today:

```
max(enumerate(array_x), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Still looking for information on available keyword functions for min/max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you have written is

```
my_dict = {'a':2,'b':1}
min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```

actually this works on `min` function. 
so, what does min do?

```
min(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
```

> With a single iterable argument, return its lowest item. With two or more arguments, return the lowest argument.

The key here is used to pass a custom comparison function.

Example: output max by length of list, where arg1, arg2 are both lists.

```
>>>> max([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5], key=len)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But what if I want the max from the list, but by considering the second element of the tuple? here we can use functions, as given in official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min). The `def` statements are compound statements they can't be used where an expression is required, that's why sometimes **lambda**'s are used.

Note that lambda is equivalent to what you'd put in a return statement of a def. Thus, you can't use statements inside a lambda, only expressions are allowed.

```
>>> max(l, key = lambda i : i[1])
(1, 9)

# Or

>>> import operator
>>> max(l, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
(1, 9)
```

so the functions are basically depend upon the the iterable and and passing the criteria for the comparison.

Now in your example, you are iterating over your dictionary. And in *key*, you are using `get` method here.

> The method get() returns a value for the given key. If key is not available then returns default value None.

As here, no arguments are there in `get` method it simply iterates over values of dictionary. And thus the `min` gives you the key having minimum value.

For `max(enumerate(array_x), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`
we want to compare the values of array instead of their indices. So we have enumerated the array.

> enumerate(thing), where thing is either an iterator or a sequence, returns a iterator that will return (0, thing[0]), (1, thing[1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)), (2, thing[2])

now we have used `itemgetter` function of *operator* module. `operator.itemgetter(n)` constructs a callable that assumes an iterable object (e.g. list, tuple, set) as input, and fetches the n-th element out of it.

you can also use lambda function of here like

```
max(enumerate(array_x), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

So the range of functions in `key` is almost up to the use. we can use many functions but the sole motive is , it is the criteria for that comparison.

Comment: What's ´l´? When do you declare ´l´? Is it a list of tuples? Where one of them is (1, 9)? Or what's going on?

Comment: @grofte The 'l' here is a list of tuples with (1,9) one of the element in it.

Comment: here's a nice tutorial on the key parameter (new in Python 2.4) https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have objects with some attribute you want to use to get the minimum value:

```
min(my_objects, key=lambda x: x.something)
```

This will give you the object with the smallest `something` attribute.

---

The same thing exists for example in `sorted()` so you can easily sort by a value derived from the object. Imagine you have a list of people and want to sort by first name, then last name:

```
people.sort(key=lambda x: (x.first_name, x.last_name))
```

Comment: As far as i can tell, my question is not directly related to lambda functions (though I understand that a lambda could be used as a keyword function).